# Printing element of 2d array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, 2d

I'm attempting to customize the "Page-Based Application" template and am new to Swift (and all programming for that matter). In my ModelController.swift I've created a 2D array to use as the primary datasource.

However, when I go to print it or use it as label.text it is including the parenthesis. How do I get just the strings of the array element I'm calling for?

```
class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageData: NSArray = [[String]]()


override init() {
    super.init()
    // Create the data model.

    pageData = [["right", "wrong"], ["left", "right"]]

    println(pageData[1]) //For 
}
```

I'm not sure what else from this file is relevant but here's another bit.

```
func indexOfViewController(viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
    // Return the index of the given data view controller.
    // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
    if let dataObject: AnyObject = viewController.dataObject {
        return self.pageData.indexOfObject(dataObject)
    } else {
        return NSNotFound
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? `pageData[1]` is the "second row" and printed as `[left, right]`. A single element would be for example `pageData[1][0]`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What's confusing is the inclusion of "(" characters in my println() and my label.text when the result is used. Why are they showing up in my result?

Comment: The actual and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: The expected was just the text "left, right". The actual was `(left, right)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want left, right

```
        println("\(pageData[1][0]), \(pageData[1][1])")
```

If you literally want "left, right" with the double quotes included it's

```
        println("\"\(pageData[1][0]), \(pageData[1][1])\"")
```

The reason you got the results you did is because pageData[1] isn't a String it's an NSArray. Because NSArray conforms to the Printable protocol it supplies its .description when used in println.